# How to load images in gridview from json from server having list of image urls

Tags: android

I am Creating a gallery application..It is described here.
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

I am able to achieve this from drawable resources.. What i need is i want to fetch image url as json from server and to display it..
My Json Format is:
http://52.42.251.70/testData/imagelist.php

Fragment Code:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        GridView gridView = (GridView)getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this.getActivity()));

        /**
         * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
         * */
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), FullImageActivity.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

Imageadapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    DatabaseUserTable myDatadb;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    String imageUrl = "";
    String id = "";
    ArrayList<String> Urls = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.imagewall,R.drawable.imagewall,
            R.drawable.imagewall,R.drawable.imagewall,
            R.drawable.imagewall,R.drawable.imagewall,
            R.drawable.imagewall,R.drawable.imagewall,
            R.drawable.imagewall,R.drawable.imagewall,
            R.drawable.imagewall,R.drawable.imagewall,
            R.drawable.imagewall,R.drawable.imagewall,
            R.drawable.imagewall
    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 220));
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can also check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) from same site.

Comment: Your data is not response in JSON format http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/?utm_content=buffer2b790&utm_medium=social&utm_source=app.net&utm_campaign=buffer#http://52.42.251.70/testData/imagelist.php

Comment: @LiemVo is correct, you json is not valid.  You need a { before each "id" tag, you have one before the first but none others.

Comment: Sorry.. my Mistake.. I hope now i made the json correct.. But how could i achieve loading image from json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple solution:

The new data on the server: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31298901/demo/demo_image.txt

The AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView gridView;
    MyGridAdapter myGridAdapter;
    private static String DATA_URL = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31298901/demo/demo_image.txt";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        getData();
    }


    private void getData(){

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, DATA_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray allImageArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("images");
                    if(allImageArray != null && allImageArray.length() > 0){

                        ArrayList<ImageObject> imageObjects = new ArrayList<>();
                        for(int i = 0; i < allImageArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject jsonItem = allImageArray.optJSONObject(i);

                            imageObjects.add(new ImageObject(jsonItem));
                        }

                        myGridAdapter= new MyGridAdapter(MainActivity.this, imageObjects);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                gridView.setAdapter(myGridAdapter);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){

                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(6000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

The layout for MainActivity activity_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.android.vad.gridview.MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:columnWidth="120dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit">

    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

GridAdapter.java

```
public class MyGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context;
private ArrayList<ImageObject> imageObjects;

private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflate;


public MyGridAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<ImageObject> imageObjects){
    this.context = context;
    this.imageObjects = imageObjects;

    this.mLayoutInflate = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    if(imageObjects != null) return  imageObjects.size();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if(imageObjects != null && imageObjects.size() > position) return  imageObjects.get(position);

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    if(imageObjects != null && imageObjects.size() > position) return  imageObjects.get(position).getId();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = mLayoutInflate.inflate(R.layout.imageitem, parent,
                false);
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    ImageObject imageObject = (ImageObject) getItem(position);
    if(imageObject != null) {
        Glide
                .with(context)
                .load(imageObject.getImageUrl())
                .centerCrop()
                .crossFade()
                .into(viewHolder.imageView);
    }

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
}
```

}

imageitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

ImageObject.java

```
public class ImageObject {
    private int id;
    private String imageUrl;

    public ImageObject(){

    }

    public  ImageObject(JSONObject jsonObject){
        if(jsonObject == null) return;
        this.id = jsonObject.optInt("id");
        this.imageUrl = jsonObject.optString("imageUrl");
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

Dependencies in gradle build

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```

Comment: Great.. It Works Perfect.. But i would like to know something.. When i add this to fragement runOnUiThread is showing error.. Also how could i show a loading? Blank screen is showing..

Answer (score 2):

You can use **picasso** library to do the same.

**configuration**

put `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`in your module level build.gradle file.

**Uses**

replace `imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);`
with `Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("URL of the image").into(imageView);`

For your url it seems a list of image urls. so you can pass this list to your adapter after getting the response.

Comment: GridView gridView = (GridView)getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_view) gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this.getActivity())); @Manu Sharma I used this to call the adapter.. How could i load the images from server to a list and pass to Adapter.. I could use asyc task to fill the list. But after that how could i pass them to adapter

Comment: When you get the List of URLs from server. Pass it to your adapter constuctor. Change signature of your adapter constuctor to `public ImageAdapter(Context context,List<String> urls){mContext = context;`

Comment: When you get the List of URLs from server. Pass it to your adapter constuctor. Change signature of your adapter constuctor to `public ImageAdapter(Context context,List<String> urls){mContext = context;mUrls=urls` and change `gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this.getActivity()));` to `gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this.getActivity(),urls/*which is list of url strings*/));`. try it and tell me if face any problem.

Comment: And I would suggest using volley or retrofit instead of AsyncTask, performance is way better. Plus using retrofit is very very easy.

Comment: I used Picasso.with(getActivity).load(mUrls).into(imageView) but i got error showing i cant use getActivity and cannot resolve method load as i used mUrls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124849/discussion-between-karthik-cp-and-manu-sharma).